# How to implement a use case with the new Firebase Custom Authentication maximum expiration time set to 1 hour?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, workflow, firebase-authentication

**Custom Authentication Tokens & their Expiration :**
Before the ​*limitation of 1 hour*​ for each token, I was creating a custom token for each customer's server when they register. The token would be used on administration dashboard (frontend) for altering settings and for server-side settings retrieval.

**Previous workflow:** 
After customer's purchase → My Server → created Customer Token for a valid amount of time (e.g. 6 months) & sends it to the customer → Customer validates/activates the product by adding the Token to their server.

- Customer's Server:​ Uses Token to activate product. The Token then is used to retrieve settings from Firebase to the server-side.
- Customer's Administration Dashboard: Token is passed from the server-side to the Administration dashboard (front-end). The front-end authenticates and the Customer can now alter the settings.

**Taking into consideration the new 1 hour token limitation, how should be my workflow ?**
e.g. 
• Having different tokens for server-side (giving credentials for customer servers in the Google Cloud project management) and for  front-end ?
• Refreshing the token when it expires by building an endpoint in my server ?

using PHP
Thanks

Comment: I think this is also related https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/firebase-talk/ZuIt7o6WwQI/MDrNPVr-DgAJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new Firebase, custom tokens are meant to be used only from clients. 
A way in which I believe you could make your use case work is by handling all the DB connection logic from within your client. The steps to do so would look like the following:

1. Assign some special credentials (e.g. a username/pwd pair) to your customers when they sign up to your service.
2. Form the customer's admin dashboard, if the customer signs in with that credential against your backend, create a custom token for them, and send it back to the admin dashboard.
3. From there, call signInWithCustomToken(customToken).
4. Now perform all the reads and writes necessary to the DB to let your customer manage their settings.

Giving credentials for customer servers in the Google Cloud project management would be a valid option if you require their servers to access the database directly, but a service account would give them privileged access to the whole database, as well as to possibly other parts of your application, so only do this if you fully trust the servers you give these credentials to.

Answer (score 1):

If i undestand all right - better use one token for each customer server with expiration timestamp field. And if you don't going to check token is not expired on each request, make periodical process, which will disable custom servers after token expired and remove them from enabled tokens collection. it's allow you only check that token is in collection or disable customer server if token is expired.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read the long question. If I'm dealing with the customer server only its fine, but I need the token to work also on client-side (i.e. admin control panel area). 
Can the enabled server token (in the new firebase 3, its created with Google Cloud Project as JSON credentials file) be used for both customer server-side and customer client-side ?

Comment: I think yes. But in different models. All tokens not depending from expiration used to access to admin front end, but for expired tokens not enabled function to start server and server test expiration of tokens on strartup.